# Automatically format code with colouring in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, format

Are there currently any possible ways to use an element or stylesheet which would automatically format code from different languages? For example in my HTML document I would like to show and example of code a user could use in Python, however the code block is all the same colour unless I manually change them each, but I would like this to be done with JavaScript or simply through an external css file or some api which supports this.

Otherwise I'm manually having to assign a class and copy it onto each code element which would be inefficient.

Which would effectively look like this example, and whatever colour I choose to manually assign to each element consistently:

```
<a style="color: #ff7b00">import</a>
<a style="color: #001eff">def</a>
<a style="color: #001eff">async</a>
<a style="color: #ff00bf">print</a>
```

^ Above is also an example of Stack Overflow automatically formatting my HTML code when it detects it. This is what I would like to achieve.

I've checked the `<code>` element, however this just sets the format of the whole code block without any format

Also with JS an example I tried using was to replace the main keywords a user inputs into a form, it then displays the same code but with the proper colour code format, however this is also too inefficient:

```js
code = "var item = 10"

code.replace("var", "<a style="color: #ff7b00">var</a>);
// And so on with each var element, integer and strings
```

Is there another simple way I can just define its class and it automatically just auto formats the code, either what was already typed into the HTML document or a user can input into a field and it converts the user's input into the formatted version?

**Similar to how stack overflow automatically auto-formats a post if the user hasn't includes the ``` tag**

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can do this with JS, so that the code parses the source code to tokens, and wraps the tokens within HTML elements. Then you can use CSS to style the created elements.

Comment: SO uses (or initially sourced, may have its own version now) the js library: https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Take a look at [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Of course this is possible with JS but it would be very very hard

`highlight.js` does it for you, I think `StackOverflow` uses it